# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined at cartt.js:8

Tags: javascript

this is my javascript code---

```
var updateBtns=document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for(var i=0;i < updateBtns.length;i++){
    updateBtns[i]=addEventListener('click',function(){
    
        var productId=this.dataset.products
       
        var action =this.dataset.action
        console.Log('productId:',productId,'action:',action)
    })
}
```

this is in my templates--
Add to cart

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with this code.

1. You are setting `updateBtns[i]` to the global `addEventListener`. You should probably change the = to a . `
2. Where is `this.dataset` defined? It is undefined.
3. console.Log is not a function. make `Log` lowercase.

```js
// define this.dataset

let updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("update-cart");

for (let i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var productId = this.dataset.products;

    var action = this.dataset.action;
    console.Log("productId:", productId, "action:", action);
  });
}
```